# Issue in ICalendar Iphone Exporting with ASP

Tags: iphone, asp.net, icalendar

Im developing an application in HTML5, I have to enter some data in the Iphone calendar, so I use ASP in my server, and I generate the ics file dynamically. I use something like that:

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript EnableSessionState=False%>
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
%>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:Serving iCalendar from ASP, Josh Poley

BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:<%=Request("s")%>
DTSTART;TZID=US-Pacific:<%=Request("start")%>
DTEND;TZID=US-Pacific:<%=Request("end")%>

BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

this works fine in Outlook, but in Iphone and MacBook, they only accept the Icalendar when I remove the headers and use static data.
What is the problem? what I have to do to make it works in this devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the answer. The server includes invisible chars between lanes, so It formats the ics with a black starting lane, and it provoques the crash.

My solution: join together the last lane of the header with the first of the ics, like that:

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript EnableSessionState=False%>
<%Response.ContentType = "text/calendar"%>BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
VERSION:2.0
```

It is a dirty solution but it works for me